# Condense scala map

Tags: scala, seq

Imagine I have

```
case class Thing(intValue: Int, stringValue: String)
```

With this I can make a map Map[Int, Thing]

```
val myMap = Map(1->Thing(100,"abc"), 2->Thing(100,"abcd"), 3->Thing(100,"abcde"), 4->Thing(200,"xyz"))
```

The original keys in the map aren't important. I want to somehow convert this data structure into

*Map(100-> Seq("abc", "abcd", "abcde"), 200-> Seq("xyz"))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by groupBy

```
myMap.groupBy(_._2.intValue).mapValues(_.values.map(_.stringValue))
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I've chosen this reply as it seems to be the most succinct

Comment: The usual warning on `mapValues` in answers: it's lazy, so if you need to access the same key twice, it'll recalculate the value, in this case non-trivially (OTOH, if you don't need to access a key, you don't pay for it). So consider its use carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
myMap.groupBy( _._2.intValue).map{ case (k,v) => (k, v.toList.map(_._2.stringValue))}
```